# What are the differences between なさる and される?

Tags: honorifics, keigo

I noticed なさる and される are both used as 尊敬語.
What are some of their differences? How do I know when to use each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of subtlety involved, and getting it right is something that will require a lot of practice, but as a general rule of thumb, される is probably the way to go, outside of set phrases.

なさる runs the risk of coming across as needlessly deferential, which can be as bad as not being deferential enough.

In set phrases such as おやすみなさい, なさる is of course perfectly acceptable, irrespective of interpersonal relationships between the referent and the referrer; which is probably why they have become set phrases.

There are, however, three neat tricks to it:

- As a learner, you won't be judged as harshly on slips. In fact, if they are noticed at all they are likely to be ignored and chalked up to ignorance, and rapidly forgotten.
- More often than not, you'll have people around you with experience in the matter. Listen well, not only to what the person you are talking to is saying, but to what those around you are saying. Experienced speakers will give you the answer for most any situation, if you care to listen.
- When alone with someone where their use is appropriate, observe closely. If される seems to put them at unease, try to understand why and either move up to なさる or down to する. What another thinks of themselves and your relationship is not necessarily obvious, so knowing how to watch and match expectations is often more useful than a rote study of when to use what.

**Edit:**

I don't think I mentioned it explicitly, but it bears mentioning: なさる is more deferential than される, and this is their primary difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that is satisfying to me. I don't need to search further for answers after reading this I think.

http://kazahanamirai.com/sareru-nasaru.html

In short, なさる holds more respect for the other party than される.

Answer (score -4):

なさる is 尊敬語 of する
される is a conjugated form of する. I don't know the name of the form, just its meaning - to have something done to you.

Even some (maybe many) japanese use 尊敬語 incorrectly (unknowingly of course). This might be why there haven't been any replies until I came across this.

どう**なさった**んですか？ (what's wrong?)

You'll never see

どう**された**んですか？

Comment: This is really not true.. される is used as 尊敬語 as well.

Comment: In fact, the passive form is probably the first type of 尊敬語 native speakers start regularly using when growing up, since it's what you use with teachers and (older) people you've just met (「どのような仕事をされていますか。」 and such.)

Comment: Darius, are you 100% confident it is correct, or could it be they are using incorrect 尊敬語 because everyone else is (so they think they are correct).


Starberry jam, would you clarify what part of my answer is not true? Is it the entire answer?


I've watched a japanese show that had on a japanese language historian. He mentioned many people use 尊敬語 incorrectly.

Comment: Because you say される is not proper 尊敬語 while it 100% is. There is no doubt.
http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%82%BA%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B

Comment: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1055075060

You can reference this. Someone asked the same question as Strawberry jam. The best answer said this, (paraphrasing): される is used as an easy form of なさる. It's not wrong to use it but shouldn't be used in formal situations where なさる should and is the official (correct) 尊敬語.
So it's like the people shortening ’られる’ (able to do verb form) to ’れる'. You hear tons of people say たべれる but the correct form is たべられる.

Comment: @kalemeister Yes, I am sure. The 文化庁 (Agency for Cultural Affairs), which is as official a source as you're going to get, includes (ら)れる as a form of 尊敬語 in its [敬語の指針](http://www.bunka.go.jp/seisaku/bunkashingikai/sokai/sokai_6/pdf/keigo_tousin.pdf). This is a topic where both the prescriptive source and the actual usage patterns agree: される is perfectly valid 尊敬語.

Comment: It doesn't say it's incorrect, only that it feels more casual to the one who answered the question. I'm not satisfied with that answer because the poster presented very little justification to it. It might be true but it also might not be.. I'm interested in seeing what people here have to say about this, anyway.

Comment: This could be a case where usage dictates convention. される could be acceptable nowadays in most situations.

A similar question for English use might be "is using contractions in formal speech or writing improper?" I think many people would consider it OK to use contractions even in formal speech, while some might try to avoid them and consider it incorrect, correct use would be subject to debate.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, What I'm guessing you're referring to.
http://www.bunka.go.jp/seisaku/bunkashingikai/sokai/sokai_6/pdf/keigo_tousin.pdf (page 24)

.....(ら)れる（例：読む→読まれる，利用する→利用される，始める→始められ
る，来る→来られる
(注) 「ご......される （ 御説明される 「御利用される」など）は，本来，尊敬語の適切な形ではないとされている。  How should this be interpreted?

Comment: A lot of modern 尊敬語 verbs were actually derived from historical passives - なさる being one of them, derived from the passive of なす. Does that not count as a strike in the passive's favour?

Comment: @kalemeister The "適切な形ではない" 注 half of what you pasted there is referring to ご〜される being unaccepted, not 〜(ら)れる or 〜される in general. The first half of what you pasted is indeed what I was referring to.